# Airflow DAG using a custom operator not working when python code for operator is placed in seperate file

Tags: airflow

I created a custom airflow operator, basically modified some code related to run_id for TriggerDagRunOperator and named it as CustomTriggerDagRunOperator.

This new operator is working fine. When I place the operator class in my DAGs code then my dag runs fine and the modifications are also performed as expected.
But when I created a seperate python file for this operator say, my_custom_operator.py and placed this file in the same folder as DAG. Thereafter, added import statement in DAG as *from my_custom_operator import CustomTriggerDagRunOperator*. The airflow UI doesn't give any DAG error. But when I try to run the DAG it doesn't work nor does it display any logs, even the tasks not related to this operator also fail to execute. It is confusing as I just shifted the code related to operator to a different file so that the custom operator can be used accross all my DAGs. Need some suggestions.

Airflow Version: 2.1.3
Using Astronomer, hosted on Kubernetes

Comment: you might need to put it under include folder. see https://docs.astronomer.io/astro/develop-project

Answer (score 1):

In order to import classes/methods from your module, you need to add the module package to python path, in this case the `DagFileProcessor` will be able to import the classes/methods when it processes the dag script.

```
DAGS_FOLDER/
  dag.py
  my_operators/
    operator1.py
```

In your scheduler and all the workers, you need to set change the python path to `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/DAGS_FOLDER`, and in your dag script, you need to import from `my_operators` package and not from `.`:

```py
from my_operators.operator1 import CustomTriggerDagRunOperator
```

For your development, you can select the DAGS_FOLDER as source folder for your project, which is similar to adding it to python path.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to work. The import is working fine, so does previously.